# Get onmouseover event from app scripts addon

Tags: javascript, dom, google-apps-script, gmail-addons

Gmail shows a dialog when the mouse is passed over the name of the person who has sent the message in the inbox list. This dialog shows the user profile picture, name, address and some buttons such us send email, edit contact, etc.

I wonder if it's possible to handle this event (onmouseover) from the add-on and if it's possible to get these information (name and address). I have inspected the page and the name is settled in `data-display-name` and address in `data-email`.

I know that there is a GmailApp service which allows you to get these information from the email message. But in my case I would like to get the information when the `onmouseover` event is executed not when the user opens a message.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's no access to those dialogs or events in Google Apps Script

Comment: So, there is no way to handle the onmouseover event from the add-on, is there?

Comment: The only access you have to Gmail is through through the card service and doesn’t give any direct access to the DOM or mouse events.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for documentation purposes:

@Copper -> There's no access to those dialogs or events in Google Apps Script

@Copper -> The only access you have to Gmail is through through the card service and doesn’t give any direct access to the DOM or mouse events.

---

You could also do it as a chrome extension so you can access the mouse. Here you have how to get started:

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted